# DNN Login across multiple sites

Tags: dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke

I am authenticating users via an external Web API.  If successful, I want to automatically log the users in to the DNN Site WITHOUT creating users on the DNN site.  Please can anyone tell me if this is possible before I waste any time on trying to implement it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A DNN User account is necessary in order for the Page, Asset, and Module security to work properly.  Every authentication provider I have built required me to create the DNN user the first time the user logged in.

That said, you could code your authentication provider to login every user as the same DNN user provided they don't see any user profile information on the UI.  In other words, you check their individual credentials with the 3rd party login system, but your provider just uses one DNN user internally to open the user session.

For more information on Authentication Provider development, subscribe to DNNHero.com, watch my 5-part series on DNN Authentication Provider development, and download the source code project to get you started.

https://www.dnnhero.com/Premium/Tutorial/ArticleID/295/DNN-authentication-overview-and-basic-customizations-Part-1-5

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.  That's very helpful and has saved me a lot of time.  I will take a look at your videos too.